# Connect to VPN in Genymotion Android using OpenVPN Connect

Tags: android, vpn, genymotion, openvpn

I am trying to use OpenVPN connect in a Genymotion desktop (3.0.4) emulated Galaxy S10. When I try to connect the VPN the emulated device hangs and no longer responds in the console. I have to restart the virtual device. The VPN profile I am using works on a physical Android device without issue.

I have tried altering network adapter configurations, this does not change behavior.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Almost every vpn provide options to modify apps which bypass the vpn connection (in fancy word split tunneling) so just select one apps that you need to use through vpn or just allow all system apps bypass vpn connection.

Just go to your vpn profile and adjust the settings as suggested.